# Remove non-existing directories from `$PATH` environment variable

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path-variables

Removing non-existing directories from the `PATH` environment variable, it's a neat way to manage your PATH. You add all locations which could ever exist, then remove all those which don't. It's a lot dryer than checking for the existence of the directory upon addition.

I recently wrote a dash/bash function to do this, so I thought I'd share it since apparently this hasn't been addressed anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

## `path_checkdir`

This code is dash-compatible.

```
path_checkdir() {

    keep_="="
    remove_="_"

    help='
Usage: path_checkdir [-v] [-K =] [-R _] [-i $'\n']

    -i ignore_this_path
Accept the specified path without checking the existence of the directory.
/!\ Beware, specifying it more than once will overwrite the preceding value.
I use it to keep single newlines in my $PATH.

    -v
Tell which directories are kept and which are removed.

    -K marker_keep_path
    -R marker_remove_path
Replace the default values (= for -K and _ for -R) used by -v to tell what is
kept and what is removed.
'

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        case "$1" in
        "-v") verbose=t;;
        "-i") shift; ignore="i$1";;
        "-K") shift; keep_="$1";;
        "-R") shift; remove_="$1";;
        "-h"|"--help") echo "$help"
        esac
        shift
    done

    # /!\ IFS characters are stripped when using `read`
    local oIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=''
    # /!\ Beware pipes. They imply subshells
    # The usuall alternative is to use process substitution, but it
    # won't work with dash, so I used file descriptor redirections
    # instead.
    {
    PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | {
    P=""
    while read -rd: dir
    do
        if [ "i$dir" = "$ignore" ] || [ -d "$dir" ]
        then
            # If -v is provided, be verbose about what is kept (=) and
            # what is removed (_).
            if [ $verbose ]
            then echo "$keep_$dir" >&3
            fi
            P="$P:$dir"
        else
            if [ $verbose ]
            then echo "$remove_$dir" >&3
            fi
        fi
    done
    echo "${P:1}"; })"
    } 3>&1
    IFS="$IFS"
}
```

Now, there is still a lot to improve. It accepts only one path exception while it would be great to accept any number and probably to support wildcard patterns too. More important, if some paths of `$PATH` contain a `~`, they won't be correctly interpreted and will be removed. I'm not sure what are all the shell expansions done to `$PATH`, nor how to re-create them. I'll probably add support for that in the future.